# How to pass a list of paths from a variable to an options of GNU updatedb

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, gnu, locate

I want to update the `locatedb` in a shell script via GNU updatedb on macOS.

The final command invocation looks like this:

```
updatedb --localpaths='/' --prunepaths='/System /Volumes/MyFirstVol /Volumes/MySecondOne /Volumes/NumeroThree'
```

However the volumes `/Volumes/MyFirstVol`, `/Volumes/MySecondOne` and `/Volumes/NumeroThree` I have space-separated in a shell $PRUNEVOLS variable:

```
$ echo $PRUNEVOLS
/Volumes/MyFirstVol /Volumes/MySecondOne /Volumes/NumeroThree
```

(Side note: I use the line

```
PRUNEVOLS=$(echo $(ls -1d /Volumes/* | grep -v /Volumes/IndexMe))
```

to initialise $PRUNEVOLS.)

My question is: ***How can I use $PRUNEVOLS in the updatedb invocation?***

---

I tried various invocations in my shell scrpt::

- `updatedb --localpaths='/' --prunepaths='/System $PRUNEVOLS'` - This doesn't work because $PRUNEVOLS is not expandd
- `updatedb --localpaths='/' "--prunepaths='/System $PRUNEVOLS'"` - Here $PRUNEVOLS is expanded, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `--prunepaths="'/System $PRUNEVOLS'"`?

Comment: Most shells use a colon `:` as separator when handling collections of paths. Look at `$PATH` environment variable for instance.

Comment: @IvanGood thinking. but this gives the same issue than my 2nd try: `updatedb` sees `/System /Volumes/MyFirstVol /Volumes/MySecondOne /Volumes/NumeroThree` as _one_ path (and therefore does not exclude any volume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the very first example (not using a variable), we can see that `--prunepaths` does not want single quotes in its argument. Therefore, a

```
updatedb --localpaths=/ "--prunepaths=/System $PRUNEVOLS" -
```

should work.

Comment: This works perfectly! I had  single quotes inside the double quotes and that was the problem.